# Chrome and JSESSIONID

Tags: google-chrome, grails, tomcat7, jsessionid

Following problem with chrome...:

I've running an Grails 1.3.7 Application on a Server. I've noticed, when I request a static content (such as non-dynamic html-files) from Chrome, Chrome creates two JSESSIONID-Cookies. The first one when the login-window shows up, and the second after a successfull login. If I want to refresh the page, or request another resource, I've to login again. (I think because Tomcat doesn't understand those two cookies)

I've tried it with FF, but FF just just creates one Cookie and its working perfectly.
Also, I've ran the app locally, and it works even with chrome perfectly. So, something with tomecat must be wrong.

Enviroment:

- Grails-Application 1.3.7 (with Spring-Security-Core 1.2.4)
- Apache Tomcat 7 (on Windows Server 2008)

My httpd.conf:

```
ProxyPass /manager http://myUrl:8080/manager
ProxyPass /myGrailsApp http://myUrl:8080/myGrailsApp
ProxyPassReverse /manager http://myUrl:8080/manager
ProxyPassReverse /myGrailsApp http://myUrl:8080/myGrailsApp

ProxyPass / http://myUrl:8080/myGrailsApp/frontend
ProxyPassReverse / http://myUrl:8080/myGrailsApp/frontend
```

Thanks in advance.

**Update 1:**

I re-builded, re-deployed the app and restarted tomcat again.

Now I noticed: Chrome doesn't generate two cookies anymore. But the error is the same. Every time I refresh or request something, the JSESSIONID changes and I have to log in again.

A short watch on the tomcat-server displays a big amount of active sessions - those from chrome...

**Update 2:**

I tried it locally on the server (with chrome):

- localhost/myApp/frontend => Apache => FAIL
- localhost:8080/myApp/frontend => Tomcat => OK

It seems like Apache is the problem (?).

**Solution:**

I've got it :)
The Grails *.gsp-Templates always requested the 'favicon.ico' on *each* request.
The reason why the error appeared on static content (like html-files) is because we redirect to those resources from our Grails-Application.

So I've put the favicon.ico in the right place, and now it works :)

This error just concerns Google Chrome, in FF and IE it worked without any problems.

Comment: Your question and solution actually helped a group of multinational enterprise developers and engineers resolve a production issue that had been occurring for months. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

I also ran into this problem. It took me a while to figure out what was happening (including sniffing with Wireshark), and still more time to find a viable solution.
At last I found this thread https://vaadin.com/forum/-/message_boards/view_message/1216366

It seams that this is a problem with Chrome/Safari (Webkit browsers?) and the way they handle redirected cookies.
The simple fix was to add a context.xml to the META-INF directory in my spring project containing

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Context sessionCookiePathUsesTrailingSlash='false'>
</Context>
```

and then redeploying the new war file. Now everything is working as intended.

Comment: But I have to admit that it suddenly stopped working for me shortly after I posted. seams like tis was part of the fix, the other part was to replace Jkmount with ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse.
Since I made those changes it works realy well

Comment: Yes, I also think there would be a few steps for a good & clean solution. My fix wasn't as clean as yours fix :P

Comment: This fixed an issue I had where a user would request "/myapp", Shiro would redirect them to "/myapp/login", and then successful login would redirect to the original request ("/myapp").  Problem was that the cookie that was set on the initial request had path="/myapp/" (with a slash), and Webkit wouldn't use the cookie on the redirect, so the user would be sent back to the login page again.  Thanks very much for the solution!