# JSESSIONID changes on request in chrome

Tags: java, google-chrome, session, weblogic, jsessionid

I have a weblogic 10.3.5 web app in which JSESSIONID is changing everytime the page is refreshed.This is causing the my application's context to be lost.

This only happens on Chrome and Safari, Firefox and IE work fine.

I've already tried adding a favicon and creating a context.xml but none of this solutions worked.

Any idea of what could be happening?

Here are the request and response headers :

**Request headers:**

`Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8

Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch

Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,es-419;q=0.6,es;q=0.4

Cache-Control:no-cache

Connection:keep-alive

Cookie:token=4955000b0d09050d0d0d1b5e5c504d484e007c1b505c494f545e48515c00710d0c090f080a05081b4e584f4b545e5452007a6f7c791b5e5c534954595c59000f1b4d5c4e4e4a524f59000b040a050b580a0f0d5e0d5b0d581b50525349525453545e545c51000c0d0d0d130d0d1b5b55000d080d0c0f0d0c090c0f090a08081b49545853595c0069786e721b484f516f585a4f584e5200125c4d4d1251525a5453134555495051;sessionid=7ai6uh9itp94rjck4nx16div8fy86wo7; csrftoken=h95iaNqxKipsA35pC6N89HzZybO9fgtP;   JSESSIONID=XWPvSbNTtpnPL5wyMyMQbJZYfXLxjqKXnJ1JMGqHvsryJV7Mh2sL!1610567454 Host:localhost:7001 Pragma:no-cache

Referer:<http://localhost:7001/ServicioPagos/app/index.xhtml?  token=4955000b0d09050d0d0d1b5e5c504d484e007c1b505c494f545e48515c00710d0c090f080a05081b4e584f4b545e5452007a6f7c791b5e5c534954595c59000f1b4d5c4e4e4a524f59000b040a050b580a0f0d5e0d5b0d581b50525349525453545e545c51000c0d0d0d130d0d1b5b55000d080d0c0f0d0c090c0f090a08081b49545853595c0069786e721b484f516f585a4f584e5200125c4d4d1251525a5453134555495051&q=1> User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.76 Safari/537.36`

**Response headers:**

`Content-Type:text/html

Date:Sun, 19 Jan 2014 03:59:52 GMT

Set-Cookie:JSESSIONID=QgptSbNYvQT1TZCxlj6ylDmxQggMLGM5RTnnrnzrR5bnx1JNq99x!1610567454;   path=/; HttpOnly
Transfer-Encoding:chunked

X-Powered-By:Servlet/2.5 JSP/2.1

X-Powered-By:JSF/2.0`

Comment: See if the answer in [**this post**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8880592/chrome-and-jsessionid?rq=1) would help you as well.  Though [the forum post](https://vaadin.com/forum#!/thread/1216367) it's based on says that glassfish automatically adds `/`.

Comment: @PM77-1 Thank you so much! I can't believe it worked . I've been dealing with this for a week. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. It was (and still is) at the top of **Related** links on the right side of the screen.

Comment: Use 127.0.0.1 for your host instead of `localhost`. Chrome is broken with `localhost` in some versions. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/52571143/148844 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7346919/chrome-localhost-cookie-not-being-set#7369084

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to add a session descriptor in the web.xml file:

```
<wls:session-descriptor>
   <wls:cookie-path>/app</wls:cookie-path>
</wls:session-descriptor>
```

Comment: Any idea and how can this be mitigated in jboss?We are using jboss 4.2